# I have an AttributeError, and how can I solve it?

Tags: html, django

I'm making an Online shop using Django and trying to add quantity of each product from cart and it throws the error under :

```
AttributeError at /order/minus_cart_pro
'int' object has no attribute 'quan'
```

I also have same errors from `/order/add_cart_pro` when I click the "+" and "-" button in my template.

What can I do and how can I solve it?
Or how can I increase and decrease the quantity instead of clicking "+" and "-" button?

this is my views :

```
def add_cart(request) :
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    cart = Order.objects.get(prod_num_id = pnum)
    cart.save()  # save 호출
    return redirect( "add_cart_pro" )

def add_cart_pro(request):
    memid = request.session.get( "memid" )
    cart = Order.objects.filter(order_id_id = memid)
    member = Sign.objects.get(user_id = memid)
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    template = loader.get_template("cart_view.html")
    for add in cart :
        cart += add.quan.quan + 1
    context = {
        "memid":memid,
        "cart":cart,
        "member":member,
        "pnum":pnum,
        }
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )

def minus_cart(request):
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    cart = Order.objects.get(prod_num_id = pnum)
    cart.save()  # save 호출
    return redirect( "minus_cart_pro" )

def minus_cart_pro(request):
    memid = request.session.get( "memid" )
    cart = Order.objects.filter(order_id_id = memid)
    member = Sign.objects.get(user_id = memid)
    pnum = request.GET.get("pnum")
    template = loader.get_template("cart_view.html")
    for add in cart :
        cart += add.quan.quan - 1
    context = {
        "memid":memid,
        "cart":cart,
        "member":member,
        "pnum":pnum,
        }
    return HttpResponse( template.render( context, request ) )
```

This is my models :

```
class Order( models.Model) :
    onum = models.AutoField(null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    prod_num = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Sign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quan = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

Comment: Your title talks about a `NoReverseMatch` while your question talks about an `AttributeError`, quite the difference, yes? Please [edit] and add the _full_ error traceback to your question, also add the _relevant_ models (`Order`).

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: change this `cart += add.quan.quan + 1` to `cart += add.quan + 1`

Comment: Thanks alot. I've tried it but it throws `unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuerySet' and 'int'` error now.

Comment: ok my bad !  cart is the variable name in which you are storing count and also what you have queried before . Use different variable name

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer :
Change this in your `add_cart_pro` view

```
    for add in cart :
        cart += add.quan.quan + 1  # error : variable name should be diffrent + add.quan (no explanation needed i guess!)
```

to

```
    count = 0
    for add in cart :
        count += add.quan + 1
```

Modify your context :

```
    context = {
        "memid":memid,
        "cart":count,
        "member":member,
        "pnum":pnum,
        }
```

You are using same variable name

here

```
cart = Order.objects.filter(order_id_id = memid)
```

and

```
cart += add.quan.quan + 1
```

Adding integer to queryset ? That's why i changed varible name to `count`

**Same Changes in minus_cart_pro**

Comment: Sorry now I'm facing an new error `'int' object is not iterable`....how can I solve this? I know that it should be integer but as you told me in the answer code, you changed to integer. Should I change it to string?

Comment: please post the complete error traceback  , only then i can tell the reason for this error `'int' object is not iterable`